# How to convert Jira elapsed time format into just minutes in an Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, jira, time-format, elapsedtime

I've been given an Excel spreadsheet with a "Time Spent" column that has values in the standard Jira time tracking format, splitting into days, hours and minutes:

```
Time Spent (Jira format)
------------------------
1d 7h 30m
30m
20d 5m
```

It can't be regenerated - it was from a particular point in time and the figures have moved on. I need to convert these times into just the number of minutes - e.g. the results from above should be:

```
Time Spent (minutes)
--------------------
1890
30
28805
```

This needs to all happen in Excel, ideally using just a formula that would work for all such time spans - would prefer to avoid VBA if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break it down into steps.
How many Days?  If it contains "d", then we want the characters to the left of the "d":  (Multiply by `24` for hours or `1440` for minutes)

```
IF(ISERROR(FIND("d",A1)),0,LEFT(A1,FIND("d",A1)-1))
```

How many Hours?  Well, if it contains "h", then we want the number to the left of the "h".  If we grab the 2 characters to the left, that will either be a 2-digit number, or a space and a 1 digit-number.  We can then use `TRIM` to strip the extra spaces:  (Again, multiply by 60 for minutes)

```
IF(ISERROR(FIND("h",A1)),0,TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)-2,2)))
```

How many Minutes?  That's basically the same as for Hours, but looking for "m" instead of "h" - and no need to convert it either.

```
IF(ISERROR(FIND("m",A1)),0,TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)-2,2)))
```

Stick it all together, with the conversions to minutes included this time:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("d",A1)),0,1440*LEFT(A1,FIND("d",A1)-1))+IF(ISERROR(FIND("h",A1)),0,60*TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)-2,2)))+IF(ISERROR(FIND("m",A1)),0,TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)-2,2)))
```

**{EDIT}** *Updated code for in case the string starts with single-digit minutes/hours:*

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("d",A1)),0,1440*LEFT(A1,FIND("d",A1)-1))+IF(ISERROR(FIND("h",A1)),0,60*TRIM(MID(" "&A1,FIND("h",A1)-1,2)))+IF(ISERROR(FIND("m",A1)),0,TRIM(MID(" "&A1,FIND("m",A1)-1,2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have just tested this out and it is currently returning `#VALUE!` when there is a single digit for the hours or minutes - e.g. for for "7h 30m". Guess some `MAX(..., 1)` may be needed in case subtracting 2 returns 0 or negative?

Comment: Oops - sorry about that.  Yeah, it's that or prepend a space to the string you are processing & only subtract 1.

Comment: Nice tutorial material *(+1)*

Comment: @Chronocidal Thanks for the update - now seems to be working nicely.

Answer (score 3):

When your data is on Col:A starting from A3, you may use this formula and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(MID($A3,1,FIND("d",$A3)-1),0)*24*60+IFERROR(MID($A3,FIND("h",$A3)-IF(FIND("h",$A3)<3,1,2),IF(FIND("h",$A3)<3,1,2))*60,0)+IFERROR(MID($A3,FIND("m",$A3)-IF(FIND("m",$A3)<3,1,2),IF(FIND("m",$A3)<3,1,2)),0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have just tested this out and it currently doesn't seem to be including hours in the result. E.g. the formula applied to "7h 30m" gives 30.

Comment: @SteveChambers It's the same issue as with my original code (starting with a single-digit hour/minute) except this returns `0` hours instead of `#VALUE!` hours.  Testing on "7m" would return `0` too

Comment: I have added an extra condition and edited the answer. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for the update - now seems to be working nicely.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers worked for me when data included weeks or minutes, with arbitrary number of digits, so I revamped the previous answers to get

```
=SUM(SUMIF(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(\d+)w") * 40, ">#N/A")) + SUM(SUMIF(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(\d+)d") * 8, "<>#N/A")) + SUM(SUMIF(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(\d+)h") * 1, "<>#N/A")) + SUM(SUMIF(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(\d+)m") /60, "<>#N/A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to write a formula to parse "w", "d", "h" delimiters from JIRA estimates. For example "4w 2d 3h" in a column. The result was this:

```
=if(C2 <> "", SUM(SUMIF(REGEXEXTRACT(C2, ".*([\d]+)w.*") * 40, "<>#N/A"), SUMIF(REGEXEXTRACT(C2, ".*([\d]+)d.*") * 8, "<>#N/A"), SUMIF(REGEXEXTRACT(C2, ".*([\d]+)h.*"), "<>#N/A")), "")
```

It's probably best you don't look too hard into it. This uses regular expressions, so beware (in case your column has other data).